# how to get Date and Time in 2 digit format?

Tags: python

How to get Date and Time in 2 digit format?

using `datetime.now()` giving long list like `2020-02-24 10:04:36.593304` like to separate them

Desire format is for output:

```
year=2020
month=02
day=24
hour=10
minute=04
second=36
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Have you read the relevant docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have everything in `curret_t=datetime.now()`
`current_t`+`.` will give you each desire value

```
curret_t=datetime.now()
print(curret_t.year, curret_t.month, curret_t.day,curret_t.hour,curret_t.minute,curret_t.second)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
month= datetime.datetime.today().month
day = datetime.datetime.today().day
hour = datetime.datetime.today().hour
min = datetime.datetime.today().minute
sec = datetime.datetime.today().second
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation of how and why they work.